# Bing Map Tiles 3D buildings

Tags: bing-maps

When I view bing maps in the browser 3d buildings are displayed
[image]

If I load BingMap tiles using their API or in OpenLayers, leaflet etc, no buildings are displayed.

[image]

Are the maps tiles with 3D buildings not available for use in other applications?

Answer (score 1):

The Bing Maps API is using http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net for map tiles (no 2.5D Buildings)

Example:
http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r0212300302202003.jpeg?g=2520&mkt=en-US&shading=hill

[image]

Where Bing Maps (browser) is using dynamic tiles

Example: (with 2.5D Buildings)

http://ak.dynamic.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/02123002133113312?mkt=en-us&it=G,VE,BX,L,LA&shading=hill&og=47&n=z

[image]

So this not supported in the API
but you could redirect the tile request (break the terms of the api maybe a grey area)

See New Map Tiles URL Format Issues
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/618e5f6c-7222-446f-b738-7f57a2e2b592/new-url-templates-for-bing-maps-tiles?forum=bingmapsservices